# Google translate api 403 forbidden in java

Tags: java, google-api, google-translate

I use API from Google Translate in order to use text to speech, but when i running this code and put my key api in key:
private static final String BASE_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=[key]&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de";

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    say("Hallo Welt");

}
public static void say(String text) {
    try {
        File f = new File("translate_tts.mp3");
        String sentence = URLEncoder.encode(text,"UTF-8");
        String urlString = MessageFormat.format(BASE_URL, sentence,"en");
        BinaryResource res = new Resty().bytes(new URI(urlString));
        res.save(f);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
        Audio audio = Audio.getInstance();
        audio.play(in);

        Player p = new Player(in);

        p.play();

        p.close();
        f.delete();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have error 403 and wrong on server returned HTTP response code. Can you help me to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Google shut down its translate webservice years ago.  Currently it is only available via the webpage.

Comment: What is the name of api from google api which i can use text to speech? I had known that the google translate api is included text to speech ( for detail, i use this api to detect and speak Vietnamese Text.